# CakePHP - Just Layout?

Tags: php, json, cakephp, layout, view

I want to set `$this->layout` to `json` in the controller action.

In the `json` layout, there will be a line saying `$this->Javascript>object();` which will parse through the data given to it by the controller, and output the jSON.

However, creating a new view file for each jSON request, eg. `recipe_view`, `ingredient_view` isn't necessary, I just need a layout.

Is there a way to bypass the view file altogether and have just the layout, without the notorious **Missing View!** error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@pleasedontbelong's solution works. You can also create a layout and view for ajax.

Your layout can be something like this:

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout;?>
```

And then you can create an ajax view like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Js->object($result);?>
```

And then from your controller...

```
public function savecontent(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->set('result', false);

    if(!empty($this->data)){
        $data = $this->data;

        //Do something with your data

        //send results to view
        $this->set('result', $myNewData);
    }

    $this->render(null, 'ajax','/ajax/ajax');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hmmm it should be something like this: (not tested)

```
function action(){
    $this->autoLayout = $this->autoRender = false;

     // your code

    $this->render('/layouts/json');
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

In config/routes.php:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

In app_controller.php:

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
var $helpers = array('Js');

function render($action = null, $layout = null, $file = null) {
    switch($this->RequestHandler->ext) {
        case 'json':
            Configure::write('debug', 0);
            return parent::render(null, 'default', '/json');
        default:
            return parent::render($action, $layout, $file);
    }
}
```

In views/json.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Js->object(isset($data) ? $data : array()); ?>
```

In views/layouts/json/default.ctp:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

In the controller action you want to output json:

```
$this->set('data', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

Now every call to an action with the .json extension (www.example.com/posts/view/12.json) will output a json object without having to call the render function in each action.

Answer (score 2):

This has been made SUPER easy with CakePHP 2.1. [See documentation here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-1.html#jsonview).

1. In your AppController, add this line after the class has been declared:

   public $viewClass = 'Json';
2. Next, add this line to the end of your Controller action, including any data you would like displayed in json format:

   $this->set(compact(array('dataSet1', 'dataSet2')));

   $this->set('_serialize', array('dataSet1', 'dataSet2'));

And that's it! You don't need a view set up for this. And even if you had one set up, CakePHP would ignore it and just display the variables you indicated in the '_serialize' array.